# Are there libraries available that create an image search tool with Apache Solr?

Tags: search, solr, libraries

I'm considering using apache solr as the search backbone on my site.

Along with standard text based search of documents, I want to create an image search tool.

Are there any libraries that allow solr to create a search index of images in crawled websites?

Are there other, better, options available?

Comment: What you are asking for is known as CBIR (Content Based Image Retrieval) This is no trivial task, you need to be an expert with tools such as OpenCV and other machine vision libraries. A start in this direction was the LIRE project although left a lot to be desired in precision/recall terms etc. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As @Mikos mentioned in the comments, what I was looking for is a [Content Based Image Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval) system.  There does exist on for use with Apache SOLR and it's called [LIRe](http://www.semanticmetadata.net/lire/).
2. Here is a list of [CBIR systems on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CBIR_engines).
3. Here is the tool that I've been investigating for use with a Linux based image search system I'm working on -- [The GNU Image Finding Tool - GIFT](http://www.gnu.org/software/gift/). This is open source and seems to be the right tool for the job when you already have the database of images.